# Как можно асинхронно получить данные из базы данных, и использовать их вне функции

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sqlite3, асинхронность

Объясняю. Я работаю на nodejs с базой данных sqlite3. Есть библиотека - sqlite3.
Есть такой код:

```
function reg(id) {
    var user = [];
    db.all('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], (err, res) => {
        user = res;
        //Тут код писать для меня очень не удобно
    });
    return user;
}
console.log(reg(123));
```

В консоль выводится "[]" - то есть, значение переменной users не успевает обновиться после того как я взял данные из базы данных, и выводится то, что я задал в начале. Мне нужно брать параметр res из анонимной функции в функции db.all, записывать его в другую переменную, и возвращать. Хелп :(

Comment: передавайте вторым аргументом в функцию `reg` колбэк функцию, которую будете подставлять в `db.all`. Либо https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)